# Python Sound ("Bell")

Tags: python, macos, audio, terminal

I'd like to have a python program alert me when it has completed its task by making a beep noise.  Currently,  I use `import os` and then use a command line speech program to say "Process complete".  I much rather it be a simple "bell."

I know that there's a function that can be used in *Cocoa* apps, `NSBeep`, but I don't think that has much anything to do with this.

I've also tried

```py
print(\a)
```

but that didn't work.

I'm using a Mac, if you couldn't tell by my *Cocoa* comment, so that may help.

Comment: `import os; os.system('say "Beer time."'); print('\a\a\a')`

Comment: the question is answered but... you do need quotation marks for special control characters they are still represented as strings `print('\a')`

Comment: Does not seem to be working for me on Mojave

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Have you tried :

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write('\a')
sys.stdout.flush()
```

That works for me here on Mac OS 10.5

Actually, I think your original attempt works also with a little modification:

```
print('\a')
```

(You just need the single quotes around the character sequence).

Comment: @kecske it's common [to disable the audible-bell](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-linux-disable-or-turn-off-beep-sound-for-terminal/) in terminal configs, which would mean this "works", but makes no noise (err, just noticed your comment was posted about 9 months ago)

Comment: Works on Windows XP as well (in a console app).

Comment: I'm seeing no difference between using double quotes or single quotes, in Python3. Also, a slight improvement which avoids printing a newline after the bell character, and forces a flush without an additional statement (the flush *is* needed as we've disabled the newline): print('\a', end='', flush=True)

Answer (score 12):

If you have PyObjC (the Python - Objective-C bridge) installed or are running on OS X 10.5's system python (which ships with PyObjC), you can do

```
from AppKit import NSBeep
NSBeep()
```

to play the system alert.

Answer (score 8):

I tried the mixer from the pygame module, and it works fine. First install the module:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-pygame
```

Then in the program, write this:

```
from pygame import mixer
mixer.init() #you must initialize the mixer
alert=mixer.Sound('bell.wav')
alert.play()
```

With pygame you have a lot of customization options, which you may additionally experiment with.

Comment: `sudo pip3 install pygame` for `python3` as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42708034/2192488).

Comment: But you might need `pip install pygame --pre` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75394336/5257294).

Answer (score 7):

I had to turn off the "Silence terminal bell" option in my active Terminal Profile in iTerm for `print('\a')` to work. It seemed to work fine by default in Terminal.

You can also use the Mac module `Carbon.Snd` to play the system beep:

```
>>> import Carbon.Snd
>>> Carbon.Snd.SysBeep(1)
>>>
```

The Carbon modules don't have any documentation, so I had to use `help(Carbon.Snd)` to see what functions were available. It seems to be a direct interface onto Carbon, so the docs on Apple Developer Connection probably help.

Answer (score 3):

Building on Barry Wark's answer...
`NSBeep()` from AppKit works fine, but also makes the terminal/app icon in the taskbar jump.
A few extra lines with `NSSound()` avoids that and gives the opportunity to use another sound:

```
from AppKit import NSSound
#prepare sound:
sound = NSSound.alloc()
sound.initWithContentsOfFile_byReference_('/System/Library/Sounds/Ping.aiff', True)
#rewind and play whenever you need it:
sound.stop() #rewind
sound.play()
```

Standard sound files can be found via commandline `locate /System/Library/Sounds/*.aiff`
The file used by `NSBeep()` seems to be `'/System/Library/Sounds/Funk.aiff'`

Answer (score 0):

By the way: there is a module for that. ;-)

Just install via pip:

```py
pip3 install mac_alerts
```

run your sound:

```py
from mac_alerts import alerts
alerts.play_error() # plays an error sound
```

Answer (score 0):

Play sound worked for me. Install using pip

```
pip3 install playsound
```

To play sound

```
from playsound import playsound
playsound('beep.wav')
```

References:
[Found the examples here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/play-sound-in-python/)
[downloaded beep.wav from here](https://www.soundjay.com/beep-sounds-1.html#google_vignette)