# How to install pygame for python3.5 in Ubuntu16.04?

Tags: pygame, python-3.5, ubuntu-16.04

I've spent hours for installing `pygame`, but it I didn't succeed.

I want a detailed installing instruction for `pygame` in python3.5 in Ubuntu16.04.

And I think it's a meaningful work for other people.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You probably do not have `pip3.5` installed, so I believe you it's not been easy. So one solution may be to start installing `pip3.5`. Based on [this article](https://askubuntu.com/questions/412178/how-to-install-pip-for-python-3-in-ubuntu-12-04-lts) on how to install `pip3` in Ubuntu, here's a possible solution for your problem.

First install `setuptools` for Python 3

```
sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools
```

Then install `pip` (which will include `pip3.5`):

```
sudo easy_install3 pip
```

After the previous two commands, you should have `pip3.5` installed. Now you can simply do

```
sudo pip3.5 install pygame
```

I tried it on Ubuntu 16.04 and it worked.

Comment: Did not work for me. My Ubuntu 18.4 tells me that "python3-setuptools is already the newest version (39.0.1-2)." but if I try the easy_install3 it says "easy_install3 : command not found".

Answer (score 1):

I used the following to install pip3 on ubuntu 18.04
https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-pip-on-ubuntu-18.04/
Basically, I did the following...

`sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3-pip`

Then I was able to install pygame with the following command ...

`sudo pip3 install pygame`